# R function to combine four variables?

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

I have 4 variables (races, asian_news,black_news,nhpi_news, and latino_news).

'races' is a factor with 6 levels: White, Asians, NHPI, Black, Latino, Multiracial.

'asian_news','black_news','nhpi_news', and 'latino_news' are a series of survey questions that have 4 outcomes: [1] ethnic, [2] mainstream, [3] both, and [4] DK.

These questions ask respondents if they primarily get their news through ethnic sources or through U.S mainstream media. These survey questions operate as follows:

- only the Asian-Americans group are asked asian_news
- only NHPI are asked nhpi_news
- only Latinos are asked latino_news
- only Blacks are asked black_news

The replication data can be downloaded here:

```
library(foreign)
pre<-read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzitbwr6q2i26gt/sampledata.csv?dl=1")
```

As of now, the cross-tab between races and asian_news look like this:

```
 > with(pre,table(races,asian_news,useNA="always"))
                                   asian_news
races                           ethnic mainstream both  DK <NA>
  3. WHITES                          0          0    0   0  500
  1. ASIAN AMERICANS               770        863  294  41  142
  2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS               0          0    0   0  410
  4.BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS      0          0    0   0  520
  6. latinos                         0          0    0   0  514
  9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS           0          0    0   0    0
  <NA>                               0          0    0   0    0
```

Similarly, the cross-tab between races and black_news look like this:

```
> with(pre,table(races,black_news,useNA="always"))
                               black_news
races                           ethnic mainstream both   DK <NA>
  3. WHITES                          0          0    0    0  500
  1. ASIAN AMERICANS                 0          0    0    0 2110
  2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS               0          0    0    0  410
  4.BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS     53        366   67   12   22
  6. latinos                         0          0    0    0  514
  9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS           0          0    0    0    0
  <NA>                               0          0    0    0    0
```

One could generate similar crosstabs with the following codes:

```
with(pre,table(races,latino_news,useNA="always"))
with(pre,table(races,nhpi_news,useNA="always"))
```

I want to combine these four survey questions to one unified variable. Ideally, the crosstabs between races and the desired variable would look like this

```
> with(pre,table(races,desired_variable,useNA="always"))
                               desired_variable
races                           ethnic mainstream both   DK <NA>
  3. WHITES                          0        500    0    0    0
  1. ASIAN AMERICANS               770        863  294   41  142
  2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS              22        332   24   13   19
  4.BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS     53        366   67   12   22
  6. latinos                       142        302   47    1   22 
  9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS           0          0    0    0    0
  <NA>                               0          0    0    0    0
```

How do I generate the "desired_variable" variable? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Try with `pre %>% select(-X) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% mutate_at(-1, as.character) %>% pivot_longer(-races, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% select(-name) %>% table`

Comment: I couldn't quite replicate your code. How do I create that desired_variable again?

Comment: Can you try with the code on my solution post with `table`.  The above comment needs `library(dplyr)` loaded

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks so much. If I want to extract the desired_variable for later use, how do I do that? Is there anyway to save that variable? also, I ran into an error with the function "pivot_longer", which couldn't be found after having loaded dplyr

Answer (score 1):

We can `rep`licate the 'races' column while `unlist` the columns of interest and then do the `table`

```
table(rep(pre$races, 4), unlist(pre[3:6]), useNA = "always")
#                           both   DK ethnic mainstream 1. Pacific Islander or Asian American more <NA>
#  1. ASIAN AMERICANS             294   41    770        863                                          0 6472
#  2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS            24   13      0        332                                         22 1249
#  3. WHITES                        0    0      0          0                                          0 2000
#  4.BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS   67   12     53        366                                          0 1582
#  6. latinos                      47    1    142        302                                          0 1564
#  <NA>                             0    0      0          0                                          0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pre<-read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzitbwr6q2i26gt/sampledata.csv?dl=1")
```

This is my effort but the code may not be a little lengthy. My logic: 1) replace `NA` to white space, 2) `paste` four variables into on variable `n_cat`. Please note since you have edited the question, the output values look different from original post and those of @akrun.

```
pre[, 2:5] <- sapply(pre[, 2:5], function(x) stringr::str_replace_na(x, replacement = "")) 
pre$n_cat = paste0(pre$asian_news, pre$nhpi_news, pre$latino_news, pre$black_news)
table(pre$races, pre$n_cat)
#                                      both   DK ethnic mainstream
#  1. ASIAN AMERICANS              184  324   53    825       1401
#  2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS             19   24   13     22        332
#  3. WHITES                       501    0    0      0          0
#  4. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS    8   36    5     24        163
#  5. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS   14   31    7     29        203
#  6. latinos                       22   47    1    142        302
#  9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS         55    0    0      0          0
```

Comment: Thanks so much Zhiqiang. This works out perfectly!!

Comment: I'm glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can get the data in long format, `count` number of observations for `races` and value from different column and cast the data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pre %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -races) %>%
  count(races, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)

#  races                           both    DK ethnic mainstream  `NA`
#  <fct>                          <int> <int>  <int>      <int> <int>
#1 1. ASIAN AMERICANS               324    53    825       1401  8545
#2 2. PACIFIC ISLANDERS              24    13     22        332  1249
#3 3. WHITES                         NA    NA     NA         NA  2004
#4 4. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS    36     5     24        163   716
#5 5. BLACKS OR AFRICAN AMERICANS    31     7     29        203   866
#6 6. latinos                        47     1    142        302  1564
#7 9. MULTIRACIAL AMERICANS          NA    NA     NA         NA   220
```